# file.wav couldn`t be downloaded in Internet explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a following problem. I want to download a captcha.wav file in IE. When I try it at first, everything works and captcha.wav is sucesfully downloaded. But any other time when I click on the same link I got this error:

[image]

I don`t face this problem with other web browser.

This solutions did not help me: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/error-message-this-file-couldnt-be-downloaded-when/5ace45f0-fb06-4e5a-9532-931211c063ba

and https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-CZ/troubleshoot/browsers/cannot-download-files-from-secure-websites

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the cache. Just to clear it solved the issue.